# How to access fuelux wizard form data?

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter, fuelux

I am using fuelux wizard with a form. I am submitting the form using javascript through finished.fu.wizard event. Is there any other/better way to submit the form? When I am trying to access the data in controller, I am getting nothing.

View Part

```
<div id="wizard1" class="wizard wizard-ux">
    <ul class="steps">
        <li class="active"> Step 1</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="step-content">
        <form action="/controller_function" class="form-horizontal" id="form1">
            <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery part:

```
$('#wizard1').on('finished.fu.wizard', function(e){
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

Controller part:

```
function controller_function(){
    var_dump($this->input->post);
}
```

No Post variables are visible in controller part.(I am using codeigniter framework but I dont think that is creating any problem). What is it that I am missing here? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting the form on the `finished.fu.wizard` works. You can check this fiddle to verify: http://jsfiddle.net/yu4qeqs0/1/

I'd have to say the problem lies with your contoller code, framework, environment, etc...

Comment: You are right, I must had some problem with my controller code which I resolved and could not recollect but I think it was that I missed name as parameter to input so it was inaccessible to codeigniter controller. Thanks anyways for looking into this.